# Как вывести всех подчинённых начальника, учитывая, что у него есть подчинённые, у которых тоже есть рабочие?

Tags: mysql, sql

В таблице есть id пользователя и id начальника. Когда я вывожу просто людей, у которых какой-то начальник - всё норм. А как вывести всех подчинённых начальника, учитывая, что у него есть подчинённые, у которых тоже есть подчинённые? Какой SQL писать?
База MySql.
Таблица с полями id, FIO. Roditel_Id (ссылка на id)
Обычный вариант `select id from table where Roditel_Id = 1`, но если у подчинённого есть ещё подчинённый - естественно, он не попадает.

Comment: Напиши правильный SQL и все будет правильно ;-) А если серьезно - сформулируй вопрос и условия.

Comment: Как вариант: http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/quipo/trees-in-the-database-advanced-data-structures

Comment: Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем. Кроме того укажите используемую бд.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko, громадный респект за ссылку.

Comment: Заголовок звучит как вопрос по корпоративным интригам, а не sql =)

Answer (score 7):

Насколько я понял, проблема заключается в запросе полного поддерева некоторой вершины.

Эта задача решается разными способами.

### Способ "в лоб" - рекурсивный запрос.

В этом нам поможет такая фича SQL, как CTE (Common table expressions).

```
with pairs as
(
    select id as a, id as b from table1

    UNION ALL

    select pairs.a as a, table1.id as b
    from table1, pairs
    where table1.parentid = pairs.b
)
select *
from table1, pairs
where pairs.a = 1 and pairs.b = table1.id
```

### Способ номер 2 - Nested Sets.

Пригоден для небольших деревьев.

Смысл в том, что все вершины дерева нумеруются в порядке прямого обхода, после чего для каждой вершины сохраняются минимальный и максимальный номера потомков.

В таком случае выборка поддерева сводится к простой проверке на вхождение одного интервала в другой. Недостаток - при каждой вставки/удалении записи надо обновлять все дерево.

### Способ номер 3 - транзитивное замыкание.

Пригоден для неглубоких деревьев.

Вводим дополнительную таблицу, где храним для каждой вершины ВСЕХ ее предков. Фактически, содержимое этой таблицы совпадает с содержимым временной таблицы `pairs` из способа номер 1.

Недостаток - актуальность записей в этой таблице надо поддерживать самостоятельно.

### Способ номер 4 - материализованные пути.

Храним для каждой вершины дерева путь, включающий всех предков. Что-то вроде `1/2/5/9` или `1.2.5.9`.

В таком случае, выборка поддерева превращается в простейшее условие `LIKE`.

В Microsoft SQL Server есть поддержка этого способа в виде типа данных `hierarchyid`. Но можно обойтись и обычными строками.

Comment: *В этом нам поможет такая фича версии SQL, как CTE*  —насколько я знаю, в mysql этого пока [не реализовали](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16244).

Comment: Когда я начинал отвечать на вопрос, про mysql ничего сказано не было.

Comment: Так уберите то, что не подходит для MySQL.

Comment: Мне лень переписывать ответ

Comment: Зато можно людей в заблуждение вводить...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, можно добавить в ответ оговорку. и, кстати, не подскажете (мне проверить негде): предложенное решение с `cte` позволяет найти связи при *произвольном* уровне вложенности?

Comment: Разумеется, это решение находит полное поддерево, в не зависимости от уровня вложенности. А оговорка уже есть в комментариях.

Answer (score 2):

если я не ошибаюсь, это одна из классических «задачек», не имеющих (за некоторыми оговорками, изложенными в [другом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429242/178576) и комментариях к нему) решения на `sql` при *произвольном уровне вложенности*.

требуется *дополнение*, либо в виде обработки результатов запросов (на «полноценном» языке программирования), либо в виде *stored procedure*, *function* и тому подобном.

при двукратном уровне вложенности (начальник→подчинённый→подчинённый) можно воспользоваться, например, union-ом: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0cc7/3

```
create table t (id int not null, parent int);
insert into t (id,parent) values
 (1, null),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2),(5,3),(6,4);
select * from t where parent=1
 union
 select t1.* from t t1, t t2
 where t1.parent=t2.id and t2.parent=1;
```

для того, чтобы получить ещё третий уровень вложенности (запись с id==6), нужно строить ещё более громоздкую конструкцию. и чем глубже, тем более громоздкой она будет.

с алгоритмической точки зрение требуется цикл, но в `sql` как таковом циклов нет. они есть в *дополнениях*: процедурах, функциях и т.п.

Comment: "...не имеющих решения на sql" - неверно

Comment: @YuraIvanov, согласен, звучит не совсем хорошо, потому что я опустил оговорки. сейчас попробую дополнить.